# What privileges need to create applications in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, privileges

I'm going to do a project with SharePoint for an organization. This organization has a full account of Office365 and SharePoint 2013. My current user has insufficient privileges for creating and maintaining Web sites on that server. What level of user privileges should supply me to make applications and have total control over them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inform the organization that you need a Developer Site so that you have a location for your "work in progress".  The developer site is one for which you would have Admin rights.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/jj692554.aspx

> If you’re not an admin, contact an admin in your company and have
>   them do one of the following:
>
> - Grant you admin rights, so you can create the Developer Site yourself.
> - Create the Developer Site for you, and specify you as an admin for the site collection.